# jQuery: set max num of list elements for UL?

Tags: jquery, ajax, max

hey,
I'm loading searchresults (list-items) with ajax.
Every loaded and matched list-item has a class of .matched.

How can I set a max number of .matched li-items inside of my ul.searchresults?

any idea how I could do that.

regards

Comment: How are you populating your list? If you loop over each item to add just check the count.  If you set via .html then you'll need to adjust the HTML before setting it. If however the issue is that too many results are being returned in the first place you'll need to adjust your server side code to truncate the results.

Comment: provide some code or anyway more details please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// global code or where ever you store that info
var MAX = 10;

// after you load the search results ...
$('#results').children('.matched').slice(MAX).hide();
```

(the #results element is the UL element, so its children will be the LI elements)